# less searches are always case-insensitive

Tags: less, case-sensitivity

Trying to find out how to use case-insensitive searches in `less` I found [this on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/11736/gnu-less-how-can-i-search-while-ignoring-case-sensitivity-without-using-less-i).

That seems to perfectly answer my question. The problem is: It doesn't work like that here (OpenSUSE 13.1; less 458).

I had aliased `less` to `less -WiNS` but I changed that. But even calling it as `command less file` does not change anything. I have checked with `ps` that there is no `-i` option in the command line any more.

As the answer says the `less` help (pressing `h`) states that I can use `-i` within `less`, too. If I use that once then `less` tells me it had changed to case-insensitive search (that is kind of correct: nothing changes). If I use it twice then `less` tells me it had turned to case-sensitive search. And right, then it works as it should from the start. Giving `-i` twice on the command line does not work, though.

What's up here?

Comment: GNU less doesn't work like that for me (i.e., it is by default case sensitive).  Are you sure it's not aliased?  What options are you using with `ps` to check that?

Comment: Hmm. Never noticed this but you're absolutely correct. Searching for FOO finds just `FOO`, but searching for `foo` finds `foo` & `FOO`. Even with the `-i` and `-WiNS`.

Comment: @goldilocks With `ps` I get either no (`command less`) options or `-WNS` so I am quite sure this is not a `ps` problem hiding `-i`/`-I`. `less` seems to have not even the possibility of a config file which could intervene here.

Comment: @slm "even with -i" is kind of funny because `-i` is supposed to do exactly that. The interesting question is: Does your less match `FOO` for `foo` **without** `-i`?

Comment: Nope it works the other way. `FOO` only matches `FOO`. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @goldilocks I have `less` 458; which is yours?

Comment: On my Debian, with `less 458 (GNU regular expressions)`, searching for `foo` matches `foo` and not `Foo` or `FOO`. Searching for `FOO` matches `FOO` alone. If run with `-i`, `foo` matches `foo`, `Foo` and `FOO`. Which version of `less` do you have?

Comment: I have `less 458 (POSIX regular expressions)` as well (Fedora 20 x86_64), and FOO will not match foo without `-i`.  What's your `$LANG`?  The C lib applies locale to determine upper/lower case differences.

Comment: I have less 458 as well.

Comment: @terdon Mine is `de_DE.UTF-8`. But calling as `LC_ALL=C LANG= less file` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I was asking about the version of `less`.

Comment: @terdon As I already said: I have 458, too.

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes I'd missed that. I wonder if it has something to do with GNU vs POSIX regular expressions? Though I really don't know why it should.

Comment: @terdon I have used simple text strings (like `foo`) only.

Answer (score 120):

I'm not sure how to enable this from the command line but when you're inside of `less` you can toggle the behavior you want by giving the `-i` command to `less`.

*toggling `-i`*

[image: ss #1]        [image: ss #2]

*searching for `/blah` and `/BLAH`*

[image: ss #3]       [image: ss #4]

*searching for `/Blah`*

[image: ss #5]

Apparently you can also summon this mode on demand by suffixing your searches with a `-i`.

#### Example

```
less prompt> /search string/-i
```

#### References

- [How do you do a case insensitive search using a pattern modifier using less?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828/how-do-you-do-a-case-insensitive-search-using-a-pattern-modifier-using-less)

Comment: That works for me, too, but I have to enter that twice. I guess I will write a bug report for openSUSE.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - It seems to stay as the default if you exit and come back in, can you confirm that behavior?

Comment: No, but I have found out something interesting (not related to this "bug", though): You can use `-i` even after a search. The highlighting changes then (if it is active yet).

Comment: @HaukeLaging - ah yes that's it. So the notation is a bit squirrely compared to other tools. `/search string/-i`.

Comment: Suffixing doesn't appear to work in `less 487 (GNU regular expressions)` (from Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Suffixing `-i`, like `/Throw/-i`, in `less env` does not work in `less 551`, Lubuntu 20.04 and `toggling` does not work either. I am less-lost?

Comment: You can also toggle this setting live while `less` is running by typing `-i` and pressing `Enter`.

Answer (score 15):

You can start less and ignore case by passing the -i option.  This ignores case unless the search string has an upper-case character.  Here is the summary on less from the [Ubuntu help page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/less.1.html):

> ```
>    -i or --ignore-case
>           Causes searches to ignore case; that is, uppercase  and  lowercase  are  considered
>           identical.   This  option  is ignored if any uppercase letters appear in the search
>           pattern; in other words, if a pattern contains uppercase letters, then that  search
>           does not ignore case.
>
>    -I or --IGNORE-CASE
>           Like -i, but searches ignore case even if the pattern contains uppercase letters.
> ```

Other versions of less may vary in their interpretations of -i.

Comment: Once you have started `less`, you can type `-i` , and it will enable the ignore case option. You don't have to pass it as an argument in the command-line.

Answer (score 12):

The manual (for my `less`, version 444) says:

```
      Options are also taken from the environment variable "LESS".  For exam‐
   ple, to avoid typing "less -options ..." each time less is invoked, you
   might tell csh:

   setenv LESS "-options"

   or if you use sh:

   LESS="-options"; export LESS

   On  MS-DOS,  you don't need the quotes, but you should replace any per‐
   cent signs in the options string by double percent signs.

   The environment variable is parsed before the command line, so  command
   line  options  override  the  LESS  environment variable.
       On  MS-DOS,  you don't need the quotes, but you should replace any per‐
   cent signs in the options string by double percent signs.

   The environment variable is parsed before the command line, so  command
   line  options  override  the  LESS  environment variable.  If an option
   appears in the LESS variable, it can be reset to its default  value  on
   the command line by beginning the command line option with "-+".
```

So, I would check if the environment variable `LESS` might be set somewhere, in your shell "dot files" perhaps. Also, `less -+i` should reset the `-i` to its default (which is case-sensitive). If that brings back the case-sensitivity for you, then you could just `alias less=less -+i`, maybe together with `alias lessi=less -i`.

Answer (score 9):

Quick guide in 2 steps:
Do your search:

```
:/put search lowercase word here after slash
```

Then after all the case sensitive matches are highlighted:

```
:-i
```

This will highlight all matches regardless of case.

Comment: It works if I enter `type`, then `Type` found. If I enter `Throw`, `throw` not found.Wait, see Oday's answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can pass parameter to the less command when you open your file, and all your searches will be case insensitive.

```shellsession
$ less -i <file_name>
```

or you can modify your `.bashrc` file so it your less will always be case-insensitive

```bash
export LESS="-i"
```

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I had something of the opposite problem: on the system I was working on, searches within `less` were *always* case insensitive. After some investigation, I discovered that the `$LESS` shell environment variable was being set to a default value, which included the `-I` flag. I was able to override the defaults by setting it within my user shell setting (`~/.bashrc`).

If you are experiencing something similar (with `less` behaving differently to what you would expect without explicitly directing it to run in case-insenstive mode, for example), you could try running `env | grep LESS`.

Comment: `env | grep LESS` instead of just `echo "$LESS"`? ;-)